# Which animator should I use to swap UILabel.text values?

Tags: swift, animation

I'm trying to swap only UILabel text values of two different UILabels.. 
I'm now doing it with UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) but it seems it doesn't animate at all.

[image]

Here's my current code ,

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var positionLabel1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var positionLabel2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var emailLabel1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var emailLabel2: UILabel!


struct Person{
    var name: String?
    var position: String?
    var email: String?
}


@IBAction func clickMe2Tapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("first click me tapped")
    var tempPerson = Person()
    tempPerson.name = nameLabel1.text
    tempPerson.position = positionLabel1.text
    tempPerson.email = emailLabel1.text

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.nameLabel1.text = self.nameLabel2.text
        self.positionLabel1.text = self.positionLabel2.text
        self.emailLabel1.text  = self.emailLabel2.text

        self.nameLabel2.text = tempPerson.name
        self.positionLabel2.text = tempPerson.position
        self.emailLabel2.text = tempPerson.email
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Exactly what animation are you expecting?

Comment: @Magnas corresponding text must be fly to the corresponding labels..  vertically

Comment: `UIView.animate` animates views. The label.text is simply a string value. It doesn’t correspond to the view that contains it. You’d need to try animating the frame of the textField or create a label (on the fly) and animate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve the goal. The following is one of them.

```
    @IBAction func clickMe2Tapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("first click me tapped")

    //swap data
    var tempPerson = Person()
    tempPerson.name = nameLabel1.text
    tempPerson.position = positionLabel1.text
    tempPerson.email = emailLabel1.text


    self.nameLabel1.text = self.nameLabel2.text
    self.positionLabel1.text = self.positionLabel2.text
    self.emailLabel1.text  = self.emailLabel2.text

    self.nameLabel2.text = tempPerson.name
    self.positionLabel2.text = tempPerson.position
    self.emailLabel2.text = tempPerson.email

    //Add animation
    let transition = CATransition.init()
    transition.type = .moveIn
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeOut)
    transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromBottom
    transition.duration = 0.5
      self.nameLabel1.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
      self.positionLabel1.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
      self.emailLabel1.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
      self.nameLabel2.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
      self.positionLabel2.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
      self.emailLabel2.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)

 }
```